# Регистрация и авторизация на сайте php

Tags: php, mysql, регистрация

Пишу биржу телеграм, столкнулся с такой проблемой: для некоторых действий на сайте нужно сначала войти в систему. Как сделать, чтобы при переходе на какую-то страницу перекидывало на страницу авторизации? Ну и как реализовать саму регистрацию/авторизацию на сайте? Интересует сам код php

Comment: Здесь не принято делать работу за других. Тем более на такой вопрос не может быть короткого ответа. Надо найти нормальную статью про авторизацию на php, создание БД, изучить и сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Если некоторая страница должна быть доступна только для авторизованного пользователя, проверяйте его авторизацию (например, сессионную переменную). Неавторизованного пользователя пересылайте на страницу входа:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  header("Location: http://example.com/auth.php");   
}
```

На странице авторизации ниже полей для логина и пароля пользователю можно задать вопрос вида: "Ещё не зарегистрированы? [Зарегистрироваться](http://example.com/registration.php)".

Чтобы пользователя зарегистрировать, нужно заводить базу данных, таблицу с нужными полями. При авторизации сравнивать вводимые пользователем данные с хранящимися и запрашиваемыми из базы данных логином и паролем. Все это делается последовательно. Одним ответом на вопрос тут не обойдешься.

- Можно начать отсюда: http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.php
- См. также здесь:
  http://ru.html.net/tutorials/php/